# Node.js Chunk data into bytes

Tags: node.js, byte

I have a node.js application that contains the following piece of code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const randomBytes=crypto.randomBytes(15);
```

Now what I want to do is to read a single each byte from 15 bytes because I want to perform a low level operation such as sending via USB in a manner that [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/52155/43808) answer explains.

But how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `crypto.randomBytes` return a buffer in order to achieve that you should put read the data by using these methods:

```
randomBytesInABuffer.readUInt8(offset);
randomBytesInABuffer.readInt8(offset)
```

Keep in mind that in lower-level languages and specifically C and C++ the variable types `char` and `unsigned char` also have 1 byte length and can be used as 1byte integers too.